# Writing Javascript code in render in class based component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a javascript if..else statement in the render method in a class based component but I am shown up an error which I am unable to diagnose.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Slider from 'react-input-slider';

class RangSlider extends Component {
    state = {
        x: 0.3,
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>{'x: ' + this.state.x}</div>
                <Slider
                    axis='x'
                    xstep={0.1}
                    xmin={0}
                    xmax={1}
                    x={this.state.x}
                    onChange={({ x }) => this.setState({ x: parseFloat(x.toFixed(2)) })}
                />
                <div>{
                    {if(this.state.x===0.8){
                        <p>Yes it is done</p>
                    }}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default RangSlider;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 3):

use ternary operator:

```
 {this.state.x===0.8 ? <p>Yes it is done</p> : ""}
```

Or if you want to skip else part:

```
{this.state.x===0.8 && <p>Yes it is done</p>}
```

Comment: recommend the second solution

Comment: Note that the second way [can result in unexpected behaviour](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-ternaries-rather-than-and-and-in-jsx)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use ternary:

```
{this.state.x === 0.8? <p>Yes it is done</p> : null}
```